# Implicit differentiation / find the equation of the tangent line using the derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So the first step in this problem is to find y' implicitly.

$$\sqrt[3]{y}=x^4-3$$

I managed to get that into this form

$$y'=12x^3y^{2/3}$$

I then need to find the equation of the tangent line at point $(-1, -8),$ but I cannot plug $-1$ into the derivative using point slope because y is on both sides. Simply plugging in $x$ and $y$ gives me an imaginary number which I don't believe is right. I'm definitely stuck and could use any advice, thanks in advance.

Comment: Does "cbrt" mean "cube root?"

Comment: Yes it does, I didn't know if that or ^(1/3) would be more legible

Comment: You should use [MathJax](https://pic.plover.com/MISC/symbols.pdf) to format questions on this site.  You'll get a lot more positive response if your questions are easy to read.  Start by clicking the edit button and looking at how I modified your post.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it

Comment: Why do you say you get an imaginary number?  $(-1)^{2/3}=1.$

Comment: Why imaginary? $(-8)^{2/3} = ((-8)^2)^{1/3} = (64)^{1/3} = 4$. And $(-1)^3 = -1$.

Comment: Geez I'm not sure, I must have been entering something wrong over and over without looking closely at the problem. Well that's embarrassing. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Just write $y'=12x^3\sqrt[3]{y^2}.$

Now, the slope it's $$y'(-1,-8)=12(-1)^3\sqrt[3]{(-8)^2}=-48$$
and the rest is smooth.